# GitLab Kubernetes integration error; configuration of Helm Tiller already exists

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

After connecting my Gitlab repo to my self-putup Kubernetes cluster via Operations > Kubernetes, I want to install Helm Tiller via the GUI; but I get:

> Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller
>
> Kubernetes error: configmaps "values-content-configuration-helm" already exists

There are no pods running on the cluster and `kubectl version` returns:

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
>
> Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:08:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

**update**

the output of `kubectl get cm --all-namespaces`:

```
NAMESPACE           NAME                              DATA AGE
gitlab-managed-apps values-content-configuration-helm 3    7d
...
```

deleting this namespace solves the issue!

Comment: Show output of kubectl get cm --all-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace with `kubectl get cm --all-namespaces`:

```
NAMESPACE           NAME                              DATA AGE
gitlab-managed-apps values-content-configuration-helm 3    7d
...
```

deleting this namespace solves the issue:

```
kubectl delete namespace gitlab-managed-apps
```

Thanks to [Lev Kuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1933452/lev-kuznetsov).